# Scrolling to caret under keyboard in UITextView works only when not animated

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

I'm trying to scroll to the caret in a UITextView when the keyboard is shown and covers it. Unfortunately it works only if I don't animate it, despite Apple doing the same in the Notes app. I'm using the same approach explained in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html).

This is the code. It's located in an isolated project to test it without any other interference. There is only one view controller with a UITextView added to it. I'm testing this on iOS 7, both in the simulator and on a device.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedKeyboardDidShowNotification:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)receivedKeyboardDidShowNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CGRect keyboardBounds = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat keyboardDistanceFromBottomOfScreen = screenHeight - CGRectGetMinY(keyboardBounds);
    UITextView *textView = self.textView;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInset = textView.contentInset;
    contentInset.bottom += keyboardDistanceFromBottomOfScreen;
    textView.contentInset = contentInset;
    textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset;

    CGRect caretRect = [textView caretRectForPosition:textView.selectedTextRange.end];
    [textView scrollRectToVisible:caretRect animated:YES];
}
```

If I set the `animated` parameter in the last line to `NO`, this works perfectly (but without animation, of course, which I don't want). Passing `YES` produces strange behavior. Most of the times the view does not scroll or scrolls only a couple of pixels, but sometimes it produces the behavior I want, so the results are random.

I tried to calculate the offset of the caret and use the `setContentOffset:animated:` method instead of `scrollRectToVisible:animated:`, but the result is the same. It works if `animated` is `NO`. With `YES` it produces the same weird result.

Even more weirdly, in this second solution, a breakpoint on that line was hit twice, although the notification was delivered only once. Breakpoints on the previous line or on a line I added after it (doing nothing, just a log statement for testing) were hit only once. To add more strangeness, putting logging breakpoints on the three lines produced this result:

```
Line before
Buggy line
Line after
Buggy line
```

So the second hit on the line came out of order. Looking at the inspector it looked like all the local variables were not in scope anymore.

I also tried to put the code of both solutions in another method and call it after a delay with `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` but nothing changed, even for a long delay like 1 second. In the first solution though this double hit on the breakpoint did not happen.

At this point I ran out of solutions and this would seem an iOS bug to me, but as I said it works in the Notes app, so there is at least one solution.

**EDIT:** I did some more investigation and the bug happens only when the text view is the first responder and the keyboard is shown (I can't say which one is responsible). If I trigger  `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` from code instead of the keyboard notification, the animation works fine. But if I first call `[textView becomeFirstResponder]`, which shows the keyboard, the animation breaks again.

Comment: It's a long shot but can you check if the `receivedKeyboardDidShowNotification:` is received on the main thread?

Comment: Yes, it's on the main thread.

Comment: I found a very simple workaround. Calling `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` inside an animation block solves the problem:

`[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
 [textView scrollRectToVisible:caretRect animated:NO];
}];`

Since I'm writing this code for a book, though, I would still prefer to have a solution that works normally and not use a workaround.